# adding html inside button when button has active class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run some jQuery to check if certain buttons have the class .active, to then add a check mark inside those buttons.

I can change the HTML for all buttons if one of them has the active class but can't seem to figure for each one.

This is the bootstrap button with the toggle:

```
<button class="btn btn-vert" data-bs-toggle="button">
   Texte bouton
</button>
```

and here is the JavaScript that doesn't work:

```
if ($('.btn-vert').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).append('<span class="float-end"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></span>');
}
```

Comment: it's not clear if you need to select all elements having a given condition (the class active) or if you need to check at a given time if a given element has that condition (like you showed in your code)

Comment: the point is that you can use the css selector itself to grab the elements having that class and that code alone could be just `$('.btn-vert.active')` ... the problem is that it's not clear why you later use `$(this).append`. Of course `$(this)` is not the element you are supposed to have grabbed from the selector

Comment: Jquery works differently

Comment: the jQuery part was supposed from the fragment of code shared.. but yes it wasn't stated anywhere in the question nor in tags

Comment: yup my bad... it was indeed jquery and should've been tagged accordingly

Comment: Note: you can do this without any js/jquery.  Just using css.  With the `span>i` prebuilt into the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop trough your buttons.
This adds a check mark to all buttons with the class `active`

> I am trying to run some JavaScript to check if certain buttons have the class .active, to then add a check mark inside those buttons.

This succeeds in that

```js
$('.btn-vert').each(function(i, button) {
    if ($(button).hasClass('active')) {
        $(button).append('<span class="float-end"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></span>');
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<button class="btn btn-vert" data-bs-toggle="button">
   Texte bouton
</button>
<button class="btn btn-vert" data-bs-toggle="button">
   Texte bouton
</button>
<button class="btn btn-vert active" data-bs-toggle="button">
   Texte bouton
</button>
```

Comment: equivalent to `$('.btn-vert.active')` (by the way)

Comment: What if I want to select a div or span within said button to remove it? $(button + "> .job-checkmark").remove() or something?

Comment: @Marc `$(button).find("span").remove();` or `$(button).find(".float-end").remove();`